# Querydict not recognizing json array in django

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

Django and Django Rest Framework is not sensing the array in the following JSON object:

```
{
   "datum":
        [
             {'proposed':'20/sep/2018', "pk":"475"},
             {'proposed':'20/sep/2018', "pk":"517"}
        ]
}
```

When I do a `print(request.data)` this is the output:

```
 <QueryDict: {'{"datum":[{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"475"},{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"512"}]}': ['']}>
```

and when I do a `print(request.data.keys())`I get:

```
 {"datum":[{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"475"},{"proposed_submission_date":"20/Sep/2018","pk":"512"}]}
```

You can see that its taking the json string as the key, and not assigning "datum" as the key.

Do I need to do something else with the JSON string?

I'm doing an AJAX PUT to the Django rest framework backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fact that you see a `QueryDict` rather than just a dict is a sign that you sent your data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data.

Ensure you send the request with a `application/json` content type and it should be just fine.

Comment: worked like a charm when I added: `contentType: "application/json"` to the ajax settings. THANK YOU!!!